# Nulling members in dispose to control memory usage

Tags: c#, memory-management, dispose

A list of objects `A` are held in a cache.  At one point those objects are passed around and a property of `A`, `B` is used.  B is a large data structure.  `A` needs to be kept in the cache but at a certain point `B` is no required - and because its large we want to let it be garbage collected.

Would a `Dispose` method on A that set `A.B=null` enable the garbage collector to collect that object if nothing else holds references to `B` (i.e we would call Dispose on `A` when we no longer require `B`, or a using statement might be used to achieve the same effect).

In this context Dispose is being used to control the life time of a managed object i.e when it can be freed by the CG.

Comment: There are some contracts expected on `Dispose`. It is meant to handle unmanaged resources. It might also get called in other contexts (it is *probably* ok, but just probably, why risk.) Why not just make another method `void DisposeB(){B=null;}` ?

Comment: @luk32 that's not correct. It's not meant to handle unmanaged resources only, in fact it is expected that explicitly calling it will dispose all managed objects. The typical implementation pattern (using a `Dispose(bool)` method) *is* to null all references, but only call *Dispose* on managed objects if called explicitly. Check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) for details

Comment: Keeping it in a cache after it is disposed is a very strong code smell.  Never tinker with the IDisposable contract.  Just make your own.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes Ok agree.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agree - Dispose not just for unmanaged control but also lifetime control of managed.  But I think Im stretching its use here a little because A is not finished with.  Really I just want A.FreeMemory() I think.

Comment: No, you don't. Thats what Garbage Collection is about. Releasing memory isn't free, so the garbage collector runs only when needed. Just dispose B and set its references to NULL and let the GC do its job periodically. In some environments (eg ASP.NET 4.5) GC runs in the background, so your app won't get a hit

Comment: Yes understood that - FreeMemeory a bad name choice - but yes this would just Dispose B and set null.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant it exists for this purpose, not solely and only. If there were no unmanaged resources it would not be needed, if I am correct. You are expected to write it when you have unmanaged resources. Also by "there are other contracts" I meant precisely what you said. It is expected to release everything, not only the things that are convenient. OP use-case is probably not the one meant for `Dispose` was my message.

Comment: @luk32: "OP use-case not the one meant for Dispose" - True!  "If there were no unmanaged resource we wouldnt need Dispose" - False! - common misconception - Dispose is MORE often used to explicitly control life time of resource use that unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose is *always* used to control the lifetime of a managed object - accessing an object after calling dispose is such a bad idea that many BCL objects will throw exceptions if you do. Having no references to an object is a prerequisite for garbage collection, but the GC is smart enough to detect graphs.

For example, if A is an orphan and nothing *else* holds a reference to B, then B is collected as well. On the other hand, if something else holds a reference to B then A isn't really an orphan and will not be collected.

Nulling a reference doesn't force a garbage collection, nor should you try to force a garbage collection. The garbage collector is smart enough to run a collection only if there is actual memory pressure, as deallocation is expensive.

**UPDATE**

It seems the actual question is "If I want to release A.B without actually releasing A, is it OK to do it by calling A.Dispose() ?` to which the answer is "No, never".

`A.Dispose` means `A` is dead for all intents and purposes. Better add a method called `A.CloseB()` that actually calls `B.Dispose()` then sets it to `null` and let the GC collect it when it becomes necessary.

Comment: One thing to note - `Dispose` in this instance should be placed and called on `B`.  Possibly accessed through a method on `A`, but it's `B` that's being disposed

Comment: To clarify A is not orphaned it remains in use - but in a context that no longer requires the large B.  Code at this point will not ref B (and would check for null if it did).

Comment: Then I agree with Hans Passant, that's a very strong code smell, and the question needs rewording. **DON'T** call A.Dispose, add a method called `CloseB` or whatever.